# Conditionally swap axes in for loop for multidimensional list Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a group of functions which conditionally switch axes when iterating through a 2-dimensional list. So far I am using an if statement and duplicating the code inside the for loop, and swapping the axes "manually":

```
def foo(i, axis):

    for j in range(9):
        if axis == 'x':
            doSomething(grid[i][j])
            doSomethingElse(grid[i][j])
            grid[i][j] += 1;
        else:
            doSomething(grid[j][i])
            doSomethingElse(grid[j][i])
            grid[i][j] -= 1;
```

Is there an "elegant" way to swap the axes which prevents having to re-use code in the for loop for each condition? It would greatly increase readability of the code.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you make a function for the `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` block and pass as argument either `(i,j)` or `(j,i)` ?

Comment: That would work for that specific example, however, the operations on grid[][] vary greatly throughout the code. I just used passing the array into a function as an example. I've modified the answer slightly to make it clearer.

Comment: If you ain't using numpy I would suspect you want to do that? If so, a simple tmp=grid.Ttmp = grid.T would suffice, tmptmp would then be a view of gridgrid without ambiguity and you could reuse one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this solution

```
def foo(i, axis):
    for j in range(9):
        value = grid[i][j] if axis == 'x' else grid[j][i]
        doSomething(value)
        doSomethingElse(value)
```

line 3 is an inline IF statement that works like a simple IF but condensed in only one line

```
if axis == 'x':
    value = grid[i][j] 
else:
    value = grid[j][i]
```

and it's better to write only one call to your function and not including that in both blocks of the if because it's more simple to read and easy to maintain

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more concise / pythonic solution, but here's a possible improvement:

```
def foo(i, axis):

    for j in range(9):
        if axis == 'x': 
            x, y = i, j
        else:
            x, y = j, i
        doSomething(grid[x][y])
        doSomethingElse(grid[x][y])
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on the comment

```
def foo(i, axis):

    def doManythings(x, y):
        doSomething(grid[x][y])
        doSomethingElse(grid[x][y])

    for j in range(9):
        if axis == 'x': 
            doManythings(i, j)
            grid[i][j] += 1
        else:
            doManythings(j, i)
            grid[i][j] -= 1
```